# Http with useFetch changing to https in nuxt 3

Tags: http, nuxtjs3, usefetch

I would like to simply make a call to an http endpoint, however each time I try, the url changes to an https and receive an error, since the server is not configured for https.

[image]
the error on the page.

[image]
the function being used.

any insights would be appreciated. Been stuck on this issue for quite a while.

I expect the response to go through and allow for http traffic via useFetch on my NUXT application. I have tried to disabled it via nuxt.config.ts, but to no avail. Explored nginx proxy solution, but this was too complex for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is because https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests being set on the target server.

I would try to add a new header like:

`"Content-Security-Policy" : "upgrade-insecure-requests 'none'"`

which should overwrite what is being set on backend. But maybe you'd need to do more adjustments with the actual value, as there are more things to be set via CSP.

Further reading:

- https://lemp.io/how-to-disable-content-security-policy-upgrade-insecure-requests-in-nginx/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy